# Find row indices of a small array in a bigger efficiency matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance

I have an array of size 3072 x 2 and I want to find the row indices in 150000 x 2 array. For example if we have

```
A =
     2     3 
     7     1 
     5     4 
     8     6
```

and

```
B =
     1     4
     2     3 
     4     2
     7     1
     7     9
     0     1
     5     4 
    14    15 
    13    10 
     6     8
     8     6
```

then I want the output,

```
b =
     2
     4
     7
     11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `ismember` with `'rows'` argument:

```
A = [2     3;
    7     1 ;
    5     4 ;
    8     6 ];
B = [ 1     4;
    2     3 ;
    4     2;
    7     1;
    7     9;
    0     1;
    5     4 ;
    14    15 ;
    13    10 ;
    6     8;
    8     6 ];
b = find(ismember(B,A,'rows'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach meant for performance -

```
function out_idx = intersect_index(A,B)

s = max(max(A(:,1),[],1),max(B(:,1),[],1)) + 1;

A1D = A(:,2)*s + A(:,1);
B1D = B(:,2)*s + B(:,1);

BA1D = [B1D ; A1D];
[~,idx] = sort(BA1D);
out_idx = sort(idx(find(idx>numel(B1D))-1));
```

To explain it a bit, we could convert each row of two elements as a scalar each considering each row as an indexing tuple, giving us `1D` versions of the inputs as `A1D` and `B1D`. We are then appending those into one array with : `BA1D = [B1D ; A1D]` and getting the sorted indices. Because of the sorting, indices from `A1D` would have higher indices, indicating those are the matches we need to look for. That's the basic idea here.

Also, note that if there are negative numbers in `A` or `B`, we need to bring in `min` to compute `s` at the start.

**Timings and verification**

```
>> % --- Setup inputs
B = randi(100000,150000,2);
B = unique(B,'rows');
A = B(randperm(size(B,1),3072),:);
>> out1 = intersect_index(A,B);       % Proposed in this post
>> out2 = find(ismember(B,A,'rows')); % @user2999345's soln
>> all(out1 == out2)
ans =
     1
>> tic,find(ismember(B,A,'rows')); toc % @user2999345's soln
Elapsed time is 0.066226 seconds.
>> tic, intersect_index(A,B); toc      % Proposed in this post
Elapsed time is 0.010360 seconds.
```